# Spree validate field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using Spree for an e-commerce app and I'm trying to validate uniqueness of sku

```
Spree::Variant.class_eval do
  attr_accessible :sku
  validates_uniqueness_of :sku
end
```

Then when I want to create a new record I get this error:

```
undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #7):

4: <% content_for :sidebar do %>
5: 
6:   <h3>
7: <%= @product.name %><span class="sku"><%= @product.sku %></span>
8: </h3>
9:   <br class="clear"><ul class="sidebar product-menu" data-hook="admin_product_tabs">
10: <li <%== ' class="active"' if current == 'Product Details' %>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost a year...
You need to write a custom validation in model with something like this

```
validate :validate_sku, :on => :create
private
        def validate_sku
        if Spree::Variant.exists?(:sku => sku)
            errors.add(:sku, "SKU kod je již používán")
        end
    end
```